# Cross-platform Excel library for C++ that can calculate formulas

Tags: c++, cross-platform, microsoft-excel

I am looking for a C++ library to read and write excel files (xls and xlsx formats) for an application running on Windows and Mac. libXL nearly fits the bill, except I also need it to calculate formulas!

Is there a C++ library which does all this? If not, what is the best I can expect from a cross-platform library?

Thanks in advance for any help.